# jQuery causing element to jump on click

Tags: jquery, css

I can't figure this out for the life of me. I thought it was the negative margin I had on it, but it's still jumping even without it.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3yrb/1/

Just click one of the list items at the top and you'll see what I mean. =/

This is my CSS to my code:

```
#productNav {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: 200;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.selectedSubSlide {
    display: block;
}
#productNav li {
    display: none;
}
```

But I feel like the CSS isn't to blame. Is it something with the jQuery?

```
$().ready(function() {

    $('#productNavReference li').click(function() {

        var selectedSlide = $(this).attr('rel');

        $('#productNav li[rel="'+selectedSlide+'"]').fadeIn(500, function() {
            $('#productNav li').removeClass('selectedSubSlide');
            $(this).addClass('selectedSubSlide');
        });

        $('.selectedSubSlide').fadeOut(500);

    });

});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I just want it to fade in like I have in my jQuery.. not jump down and then back up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fade in the next slide after you faded out the current one, right? So do what you do with the fade in function, use the callback:

```
$().ready(function() {

    $('#productNavReference li').click(function() {

        var selectedSlide = $(this).attr('rel');

        $('.selectedSubSlide').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('#productNav li[rel="'+selectedSlide+'"]').fadeIn(500, function() {
                $('#productNav li').removeClass('selectedSubSlide');
                $(this).addClass('selectedSubSlide');
            });
        });

    });

});
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3yrb/6/

You could use `if($('#productNav li:animated').length) { return false; }` on top of the click-event handler to prevent multiple pages from loading.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, while you fading your elements at some point you have those elements at the same time on page, therefore they need to position themselfes somehow. So my suggestions is to hide first element instantly and `fadeIn` another one.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:absolute` to your `.selectedSubSlide` and `#productNav li` selectors.

```
.selectedSubSlide {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
}
#productNav li {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/E2nGN/)**